# Yii: Calling $model->save() makes call to $model->update()

Tags: php, yii

Here is a code, I'm trying to save new record.

```
...
if(!Favorites::model()->isFavorite($user_id)){
    $model = new Favorites; //::model();
    $model->credential = Yii::app()->user->id;
    $model->favorite = $user_id;
    if($model->save(false))
      echo 1;
    else 
      echo 0;
}
....
```

It prints out 1 that means query was okay but when I look at table there is no new record. When I check this in the log it is calling update() rather than save(). Here is a application log photo.
[image: Application log]

Comment: what is the value of $model->isNewRecord?

Comment: @MrSoundless: it's null.

Comment: is Favorites even a CActiveRecord?

Comment: @MrSoundless Yes. But after making isNewRecord to true is working fine. But couldn't understand the problem.

Comment: @EjazKarim: Could you add construct() and model() for Favorites model in your question?